# What is missing javaee:javaee-api:jar:5?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

I want to built my application with maven but it says:

```
Missing:
----------
1) javaee:javaee-api:jar:5

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javaee -DartifactId=javaee-api -Dversion=5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

Where can I download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://download.java.net/maven/1/javaee/jars/

Answer (score 0):

download [JDK from Oracle Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index-jsp-140710.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have jdk at my computer but I connect to my company's network over vpn and when I want to build that application with maven, I thinks it is asking for something missing a "jar file"?

Answer (score 0):

Which app server are you using?
You could get it from the lib directory of the app server.
For Glassfish, you can find previous versions at http://java.sun.com/javaee/downloads/previous/index.jsp

You could also get it from the Glassfish installs bundled with Netbeans at [netbeans.org](http://www.netbeans.org)

For JBoss, download version 5.x from http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads.html.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `javaee-api` v5 is not on maven central. It's available in the JBoss maven [repository](https://nexus.sourcesense.com/nexus/content/groups/public/javaee/javaee-api/5/).